# R/Python: Converting a JPEG/PNG Image into Geographical Coordinates?

Tags: r

Suppose I have the following image (Toronto, Canada) saved as a JPEG or a PNG:

[image]

**My Question:** Suppose I provided the region of the world and some longitude and latitude coordinates around this picture for reference.

Using software such as R or Python - are there any techniques that can be used to identify the entire perimeter of this red shape? E.g. Identify a JSON list of geographical coordinates - essentially turning this into a shapefile.

Can this be done with OpenStreetMaps?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1- You can use OCR to get bold names in your image, that is done with python and tons of free open source applications are existing in github and other location. just see which one suites you.

2- google search your location name based on what OCR found. for example:
API ***[search](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Ripley%27s+Aquarium+of+Canada/@43.6421785,-79.3887909,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m6!3m5!1s0x882b34d5d5b6045b:0x8daf1a19298c213d!8m2!3d43.6421785!4d-79.3866022!16s%2Fm%2F0vxfm_5?entry=ttu)*** for: "**Ripley's aquarium of canada**" will give you exact location and you can get coordinate easily.

I bet openstreet maps will be the same result too.